# how to just load those functions a program need instead of loading the whole libc?

Tags: ubuntu, linker

I am learning about the dynamic linker on Ubuntu.I want to import the libc functions I need,but it linked the while libc.so file.I don't know how to do that,so I come here to look for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you link your program to a dynamic library (e.g. `libc.so`) then
the dynamic library will be loaded into your program's process at
runtime. Your program itself - the output file of the linker - will not
contain any objects from `libc`. It will merely contain instructions to the
runtime loader to load `libc.so` into the process and resolve symbols.

That's how dynamic linking works. It you want to include *in your program* just the objects from `libc` that it
needs then you need to link the *static* version of `libc`, i.e. `libc.a`. That would
be unusual and is unnecessary unless you have in mind a special reason for
not linking `libc` dynamically. Linking it statically will not make your program
smaller. It will make it bigger, because the objects from `libc` that it needs *will* be embedded
in it at linktime.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have learnt about the static linking but I'm sure it is not what I need. I wonder if I can modify ld-linux.so.2 to load just the required part of libc.so? Great appreciation!